# Earthing: TN in TT installation?

Tags: power, ground, grounding, earth, floating

Something odd happened at work today: the whole building installation is TT, just like the whole country. L1-L2-L3 supplied to the transformer and then L1-L2-L3-N goes to the loads.

I noticed that we have an installation in the facility that was made in a TN way: the power cable to the setup has no PE conductor and, inside the setup, whoever did it, connected the Neutral wire to the chassis (basically everything that needs to be grounded is connected to Neutral). Is this even possible? Doesn't this pose a safety issue?

Additionally, while doing a rework, the neutral was improperly connected and so we had floating neutral and some equipment got burnt. Doesn't the former issue that I mentioned make latter worse?

Comment: Welcome! Legislation varies from country to country. Where is this?

Comment: This is in Portugal

Answer (score 0):

> I noticed that we have an installation in the facility that was made in a TN way: the power cable to the setup has no PE conductor and, inside the setup, whoever did it, connected the Neutral wire to the chassis (basically everything that needs to be grounded is connected to neutral). Is this even possible? Doesn't this pose a safety issue?

It is clear from your description that the TN-C system has been mistakenly followed in one area of the installation. The schematic of the TN-C system is as shown.

[image]

*Image Credit:  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthing_system)*

In this system the neutral cable doubles up as the protective earth conductor (referred to as PEN).

A ( PEN ) wire-break would definitely be a safety issue since a 'live chassis' fault would remain undetected till the RCD tripped as a result of personnel coming in contact with the chassis.

In the TT system, however, the main circuit breaker would have tripped immediately on occurrence of the live chassis fault.

Here's the TT system schematic.

[image]

*Image Credit:  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthing_system)*

It is incumbent on the management to revert to the TT system in order to conform to the code of earthing practice in Portugal and avoid the safety issue.

However, the 'floating neutral' problem is common to both the systems.